# why is this SVG getting cropped instead of scaled down (only in React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

When I change the width or height of the SVG it ends up looking like this instead of scaling properly. (getting cropped)[image]

the problem only happens when the inline SVG is in React. I have tried to fix this for like 7 hours but I've got nothing to work.

The SVG tag is this:

```
<svg baseprofile="tiny" 
fill="#ececec" 
stroke="black" 
stroke-linecap="round" 
stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke-width=".2" 
version="1.2" 
viewbox="0 0 2000 857" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

However, this is probably not relevant since I tested it without any properties and it still won't scall properly. (In pure HTML and CSS I can get this to work easily)

Adding Overflow: visible; does make it show the cropped area but it's still not scaled down.

Comment: viewBox should contain 4 numbers if you use px it is invalid and the viewBox will not be applied.

Comment: yea, I was messing around with those figures but it didn't work before I added 'px' either

Comment: in the SVG tag, the "viewBox" attribute is for coordinate and scale but "width" and "height" are for size.
you can set '"view box" properly once. then whenever you like just change the "width" and "height" for size.

Comment: We need to see the SVG's container element (eg. `<div>`), and how it is sized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that vanilla HTML is okay with it being "viewbox" but React requires it to be in camelCase as "viewBox"